# How to get Visual Studio 2008 to Program Files? (64-bit)

Tags: visual-studio, mpir

So I'm **following the instructions to install MPIR** (bigger integers library), which i chose before GMP, because of more information being availible on Windows download and just easier installation for typical user. Basically I found this simple **tutorial**: http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/

The only thing I've done different from this tutorial is my Visual Studio 9.0 being stored in Program Files (x86) and when I then proceed to open Visual Studio 2008, it can't find any projects in my solution 'mpir'.

And so I need not to compromise the steps stated in the tutorial (must have Visual Studio in the exact directory) and then see how things will work out.

This is my current **Visual Studio 2008 (Express Edition All-in-One DVD ISO)** download: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=104679 , which i then open using **WinRAR** and run the setup aplication that allows me to choose from four (C#, C++, Basic, Web Developer). I choose **C++** and proceed to change the **destination folder**, which is **set to Program Files (x86)** to **Program Files**, but after the installation **I always end up with Visual Studio being in Program Files (x86)**. (I can create a file with random name and Visual Studio installs in that file, also I can **move** Visual Studio from Program Files (x86) or random file to **Program Files**, but then **Visual Studio won't be detected** and I won't be able to open 'mpir.sln' in it.)

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be related to C or C++ itself, but be a compiler environment specific problem. So, please remove tags c and c++.

Comment: Why do you want that old version? There is a free version of VS 2015 available online for those who look. It is installed in `Program Files (x86)` because it is a 32-bit version. It is might be for a 64-bit PC but the target implementation is 32 bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane Trying to follow the instructions, since I don't know how to install MPIR on newer versions.

Comment: @WeatherVane Just how *free* it really is could be up for debate.

Comment: @RawN is that a troll?

Comment: Please don't start a debate on freeness here. It won't help the op. Obviously free here meant "doesn't cost money". EOD (hopefully)

Comment: @WeatherVane Certainly not. Free or not I somehow always end up paying around 1k for a pro version because that *free one* never seems to work for commercial product.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thats what I also thought, but is there any 64-bit version of 2008 then? Tried everything from microsoft's page...

Comment: It would be ideal if the link provided in the tutorial worked to show me what Visual Studio 2008 the autor had, but its just link to microsoft's page...

Comment: @BodoThiesen Don't you know about any tags I can add then? Because this really doesn't seem to get much traffic.

Comment: @SamS: Tags are not to atract trafic, but allow sorting/cathegorising a question. Please follow site-rules and refrain from using unrelated tags.